# Integrating Another Message Queue with IIS Hosted Workflow Service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Currently, I am using MSMQ to queue messages for IIS hosted workflow services to handle. However, I would like to use another message queuing system instead (eg - RabbitMQ).

I know RabbitMQ already has WCF bindings, but are there more components required for this to work with IIS hosted workflow services (perhaps some hook into WAS)? How would I go abouts switching from MSMQ to RabbitMQ, or another message queue product?

Comment: Have you tried just hooking it up with the bindings?  It might just work.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried it because I just assumed it wouldn't work. I was hoping someone has tried this already and knew how to do it. I'm hoping to get around to tinkering around with this soon.